# Is there currently a good model for unsupervised instance segmentation of cytoplasm + nucleous of pap smear test that is freely accessible and works?

Tags: instance-segmentation

I've been looking for a pap smear test **instance segmentation** model that has the code and the weights available, but most of the papers don't have code, or the ones that have, the code lacks some files / classes or has a problem of some type. I'm looking specifically for Python / Pytorch models, but is not a hard requirement. I'm looking for something that works out-of-the-box, even if is not perfect.

There seem to be models that can segment nucleus, but I'd like to have one that can segment the whole cell, not only the nucleus. I don't need it to classify the cell, just do instance segmentation.

For example, for the models listed in "A systematic review of deep learning‑based cervical cytology screening: from cell identifcation to whole slide image analysis", only the papers written by Zhou et a. seem to [have code](https://github.com/Amandaynzhou/MMT-PSM), but I wasn't able to make it work because some library requirements require admin permissions.

I don't need it to be overlapping cells although is not a problem if it can handle overlapping cells.